# Query Union remove duplicates

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

I have  a union query as below. It returns duplicate records when searh query is found between both heading and description. How to avoid duplicate records from the search result

```
    $SQL = "(SELECT * FROM {$this->blogs} WHERE LOWER(heading) LIKE '%" .strtolower($query) . "%' ) 
        UNION 
        (SELECT * FROM {$this->blogs} WHERE  LOWER(description) LIKE '%" . strtolower($query) ."%')";   
    $run = $this->db->query( $SQL );
    $this->db->last_query();
```

**Search**

```
(SELECT * FROM tbl_wonderblogs WHERE LOWER(heading) LIKE '%indian army amfc%' ) UNION (SELECT * FROM tbl_wonderblogs WHERE LOWER(description) LIKE '%indian army amfc%')
```

Comment: Please add the full code along with some sample data to your question if possible.

Comment: `UNION` is a shortcut for `UNION DISTINCT` and doesn't return duplicate rows. Are you sure you have posted the correct code?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `union` you can just put both conditions in one query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM {$this->blogs} 
WHERE (   LOWER(heading) LIKE '%" .strtolower($query) . "%' 
       OR LOWER(description) LIKE '%" . strtolower($query) ."%'
      )
```

If you need heading matches to come first, then add:

```
ORDER BY (LOWER(heading) LIKE '%" .strtolower($query) . "%') DESC
```

Still, make sure your table does not already contain duplicate data. If that is the case, you need to find out the cause and resolve that, which is better than adding the `DISTINCT` keyword after `SELECT`. That, by nature, removes duplicates from the output.